# Transition to FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can transition to a `Fragment` class using the code below, but how do i transition to a `FragmentActivity`, using the same code.

```
FragmentActivity activity = new ABC(); // ABC is a FragmentActivity
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.details, activity); // replace errors out
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't replace a view or a fragment with a FragmentActivity! A FragmentActivity is just an Activity and has been created for Android Compatibility support.

To summarize, an Activity can contains Fragments which can be dynamically replaced. The only way to navigate between Activities is by intent.

Comment: so I have to rewrite all my activities to use fragment