# Control two fragments within a tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction when using fragments within a tab. I have a mutiple tab application. On one of the tab pages I have broken down the content into two separate fragments.

The issue is I do not want the  fragment activity I using to control the tab to control also control the two fragments being displayed. I want an something between the two elements such as another fragmentactivity to control the fragments used as content. 
Is this possible and if so how?

Tab Fragment

tab 1 tab2 tab 3

tab2 : display is two fragments

tab2 -> anther fragmentActivity -> two displayFragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Transition to FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810593/transition-to-fragmentactivity)

I believe I've found my answer. This can't be done. My fragments need to response to a fragmentActivity and the fragmentTransaction only transitions between fragments not activities. So they will have to respond to my activity controlling the tabs.